# Anylogic bucle wait

Tags: java, anylogic

In AnyLogic, I need to move an agent based on a condition that changes over time. For example, `agent.Type = a`. However, I need the agents that do not meet this condition to continue waiting, and this question needs to be asked repeatedly. I am not sure which tool to use, but I was thinking about using a wait. Can you please help me?

```
if ((int) agent.getParameter("Tipo")==1)
    wait.free(agent);
```

Comment: that is correct to do... using the getParameter("name"); is so unusual though, but valid

Comment: but i need to do a bucle i dont know how to doit with Wait tool and where

Comment: dynamic event inside the agent... check help documentation on how to use it